# Make requestAVAssetForVideo synchronous

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous

I'm getting the URL from all the selected videos in gallery, it works nice.

But I noticed that `requestAVAssetForVideo` is executed in an **Asynchronous** way.

Earlier I specified `requestImageForAsset` to be executed in a **Synchronous** way by changing `options:nil`by `options:option`

```
PHImageRequestOptions *option = [PHImageRequestOptions new];
        option.synchronous = YES;
```

And that works like a charm, but it is not working as the same form with `requestAVAssetForVideo`

Is there a way to execute `requestAVAssetForVideo` in a **Synchronous** way?

```
[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:lAsset
                                                        options:nil
                                                  resultHandler:^(AVAsset *avAsset, AVAudioMix *audioMix, NSDictionary *info) {
            NSURL *url = (NSURL *)[[(AVURLAsset *)avAsset URL] fileReferenceURL];
            NSLog(@"url = %@", [url absoluteString]);
            NSLog(@"url = %@", [url relativePath]);
        }];
```

Comment: this API is taking a long time. any other alternative options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as CodeBender says there isn't but, this is a way to build a synchronous version:

```
dispatch_semaphore_t    semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

PHVideoRequestOptions *option = [PHVideoRequestOptions new];
__block AVAsset *resultAsset;


[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:videoAsset 
                                                options:option 
                                          resultHandler:^(AVAsset * avasset, AVAudioMix * audioMix, NSDictionary * info) 
            {
                resultAsset = avasset;
                dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
            }];

dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
// We synchronously have the asset
[self doSomethingWithAsset:resultAsset];
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

Long answer:

Per Apple's [documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/photos/phimagemanager/1616935-requestavassetforvideo) at the top of the page:

> Requests AV Foundation objects representing the video asset’s content
>   and state, to be loaded **asynchronously**.